# How to deploy a war via maven before running junit4 integration tests?

Tags: java, maven, junit4

I want the maven to deploy war before running the jUnit tests.

I have added the failsafe plugin and a configuration but the deploy is still done after the tests.

Are the tests not run by the failsafe plugin?

```
<build>
    <finalName>testWar</finalName>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.16</version>
        <configuration>
            <systemPropertyVariables>
                <wildfly.remote.port>10090</wildfly.remote.port>
            </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.Final</version>

        <configuration>
            <hostname>host</hostname>
            <port>10090</port>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>pw</password>
        </configuration>

        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>wildfly-run</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>

            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Do your tests use the correct naming convention that differentiates them from unit tests? See [Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)

Comment: @SteveC if you add it as the answer I accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour you report suggests that your tests are being run in the `test` phase instead of the `integration-test` phase. This is because by default both the Maven Surefire and Maven Failsafe plugins use class name conventions to differentiate between the two types of tests, as described below:

### Default Unit Test Behaviour

The [Maven Surefire Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html) runs *unit* tests in the `test` phase. By default it selects tests to execute based on the class name of the test, as described in [Maven Surefire Plugin | Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html):

- "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
- "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
- "**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
- "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

### Default Integration Test Behaviour

The [Maven Failsafe Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/index.html) runs *integration tests* tests in the `integration-test` phase. By default it also selects tests to execute based on the class name of the test, as described in [Maven Failsafe Plugin | Inclusions and Exclusions of Tests](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html:

- "**/IT*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "IT".
- "**/*IT.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "IT".
- "**/*ITCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "ITCase".

**Therefore you probably just need to rename your integration test classes to conform with one of the three conventions shown above.**